# Firefox with nvidia-driver-396 driver has no 2D acceleration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, firefox

I'm experiencing an issue with Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04 having no 2D acceleration, 3d seems to work fine, but scrolling, switching tabs, and watching YouTube and Netflix has noticeable tearing. I have the nvidia-driver-396 driver. The same issues are present with the nvidia-driver-390 driver. OpenGL games work fine, so it's not OpenGL. And I have Hardware Acceleration enabled in Firefox settings.
My GPU is an Titan Xp, and Ubuntu is up-to-date and I have third party properaty things enabled on install.(for audio codecs)

Anyone know what might be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have exactly the same issue on 18.04 with nvidia-396 on GTX 765M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by setting the option **layers.acceleration.force-enabled** to **true** in Firefox. Apparently my driver is blocked by my platform, no idea why.