# Firefox 64.0 renders content transparent

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, firefox

Since this unattended upgrade (excerpt from `/var/log/apt/history.log`), Firefox seems to be unusable because of rendering problems. The content in the main window is kind of transparent.

```
Start-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:06
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (63.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 64.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:15

Start-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-de:amd64 (63.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 64.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:19

Start-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:21
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (63.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 64.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-12-12  21:03:22
```

At first, i suspected it to be a Nvidia driver issue, so i upgraded from `nvidia-driver-390`:

```
nils@nyx:~$ apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-driver-390:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
     390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     390.48-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
```

to `nvidia-driver-396`:

```
nils@nyx:~$ apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-396 
nvidia-driver-396:
  Installiert:           396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Installationskandidat: 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But it didn't fix anything.

The problem looks like this:
[image: Problem]

Notice the front wheel of the motorbike image behind Firefox appearing in the image from the *new tab* page. This got me thinking, the parts of the *new tab* image, that are over dark parts of the image behind it, appear kind of normal. So i created a `black.png` and have this (directly) behind Firefox.

This looks like this, quite normal, as expected:
[image: Expectation]

The *About Mozilla Firefox* window seems not affected, even when the image is acquired by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Print</kbd>:
[image: About not affected]

For the main window, creating the image by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Print</kbd> is even worse:
[image: About not affected]

Only the window decorator is there, the content of the window is completely transparent.

So it seems like the value/lightness (as in HSV/HSL) from the pixel in the application behind Firefox controls the alpha/tranparency value for that pixel in Firefox itself.

After some googling I suspected the hardware acceleration. But turning it off made no difference:
[image: About not affected]

The only thing that helps, is a black background:
[image: About not affected]

When started from the shell, there is the following output:

```
nils@nyx:~$ firefox

(firefox:6467): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:50:19.849: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:34: Expected ')' in color definition

(firefox:6467): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:50:19.849: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:77: Expected ')' in color definition
```

It's the same with `thunderbird`, but there are no rendering problems.

```
nils@nyx:~$ thunderbird

(thunderbird:7059): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:52:38.204: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:34: Expected ')' in color definition

(thunderbird:7059): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:52:38.204: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:77: Expected ')' in color definition
```

Up to now, I'm out of ideas how to fix this. Does anyone else is having these issues? Where to file a bug for this? Mozilla? Canonical? I consider this a problem in Firefox, because Thunderbird is not affected. No other (bionic) application seems to be affected, too. I can't decide if this is a packaging problem or really a Firefox problem. Any help?

edit: Just for reference: My graphics card is a [Gigabyte GeForce® GTX 1060 G1 Gaming 6G](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Graphics-Card/GV-N1060G1-GAMING-6GD-rev-10#kf).

Comment: Suddenly my Firefox started doing this just now. Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit), NVIDIA GTX1080Ti, and `nvidia-driver-440` package.

Comment: Additionally at the same time the MS Teams desktop application (some Electron powered thingy I presume) lost sharp fonts, and renders them horribly, no transparency though. Chromium works well, no fuzziness or transparency, same for Spotify (powered by Electron as well I presume).

Comment: I don't have the problem atm, but I would check if the problem is gone when using wayland instead of xorg. But this is just a shot into the dark... based on hope that the future will be better. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution, but I'm not sure how this became an issue in the first place.

Quite generally looking for graphics problems in Firefox I stumbled upon [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084401/457552). I was looking in `about:config` for the value of the option `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and found it manually set to `true`. After resetting it to the default value of `false` and restarting Firefox, the issue is completely gone.

So for *my situation* the solution was the **opposite value** to the one suggested by the *other answer*.

Comment: When switching from Xenial to Bionic I experienced some tearing as described in the other answer. Maybe I tried to fix it with the solution from there, in the past.

Comment: Well, it's strange. I had the same problem but the solution was an opposite one, just like Dimitris (and the man from your link) suggested: setting layers.acceleration.force-enabled to TRUE
@dsstorefile1 Are you sure it's still not working? I'm just wondering what happens and how enabling the setting can help

Comment: I added my [graphics card](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Graphics-Card/GV-N1060G1-GAMING-6GD-rev-10#kf) for reference. Maybe there are differences?

Answer (score 11):

Having the same problem, and can't find enough info about it online!

[Strange "ghost images" / transparency effect in full-screen videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102427/strange-ghost-images-transparency-effect-in-full-screen-videos/1103067?noredirect=1#comment1819087_1103067)

For me, setting `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` to **true** in `about:config` fixed the issue, but I took a big hit in performance and FPS of my videos. There was visible stuttering.

In another answer in the Mozilla Support Forum, one other solution that was suggested and indeed fixed the issue was changing `gfx.xrender.enabled` to **true**, instead of forcing hardware acceleration.

I don't know which of the two is better.

Comment: Setting `gfx.xrender.enabled` to **true** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in Firefox 64, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1516224#c7

Comment: For me, it was not just video, but every image that was in the browser. See example images. But it may be related.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating:** In Firefox 81 on Ubuntu 20.10 with Nvidea graphic card driver v450.

**Issue:** The same problem show transparent window when set `gfx.webrender.all` to `true` in `about:config`.

**Solution:** Set it to `false` and restart the browser then all back to normal.

**One tip:** I opened the black screen of VLC player behind the Firefox window to achieve see something on transparent screen.

**Explaining:** WebRender is the brand new Mozilla render developed in Rust lang that's replacing the old GECKO render developed in C++. However, it's for experimental use yet.