# Strange "ghost images" / transparency effect in full-screen videos

Tags: 18.04, video, transparency, html5

A strange problem manifested on my machine recently, and I'm really at a loss when trying to resolve it, as I don't even know how to google this.

---

**I was watching Netflix full-screen one fine day**, on Firefox v64.0, on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 laptop. At some point, I thought I saw ghost images overlaid on my video. I thought my eyes were just tired and paid no attention to it, I closed the laptop and went to get some coffee.

Later on, while watching a YouTube video (again, fullscreen) and I thought I saw the ghost image again. I turned up my screen's brightness all the way to 100% and lo-and-behold, **I could see my wallpaper through the full-screen video!**

This has been going on for some days now, and I wasn't able to find what's causing it. **Full screen videos on Netflix and YouTube** have some sort of 10-20% transparency, and I can see my wallpaper behind them. This only happens when the video is playing. When I pause the video, transparency goes away. You can understand how this played with my mind a little bit at first.

**Local video files on my machine, played through `mpv`, have no transparency issues.**

To give you an example, I'm sorry but I literally took a photo of my laptop's monitor.

Here's a full screen YouTube video of a pure black screen, for 10 hours ([It's just a video of all-black playback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOwsLtwa2Ts)):

[image: pic1]

The image in the back (the ghost image I was seeing) is of course, nothing else other than my wallpaper:

[image]

The transparency is also captured in regular screenshots. Here's one of the above 100%-black-video **fullscreened** and **playing**. It isn't as visible because it's a software screenshot, but you can see the ghost image there too if you squint.

[image]

Comment: I really hope I'm not really losing my mind...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My config is Firefox 64.0, Ubuntu 18.04.1. Experienced the same problem. After searching and reading, finally was able to fix it.

Changed `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` option to **true** in the `about:config`

**Edit**: You may also try to create `mozilla.widget.use-argb-visuals` as Boolean and set it to **false** in `about:config`

Source: [Firefox Bug 1516224 Semi-Transparent YouTube video playback](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1516224#c7)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. May I ask how you searched for it? What did you look for? Source on what was causing this?

Comment: Searched for something like "ubuntu firefox fullscreen video transparent" and found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100753/firefox-64-0-renders-content-transparent

Comment: This did fix the issue but caused other rendering issues for me

Answer (score 1):

In `about:config` setting `gfx.xrender.enabled` to **true** fixed it for me, with no rendering issues and no loss of performance.