# desktop wallpaper shown in the background in fullscreen mode videos on firefox 64 only in user profile

Tags: 18.04

so I have a weird problem, when I'm watching a video online in full screen mode on Firefox 64, I can see my desktop wallpaper in the background when the there is a dark scene. It only happens with my profile account. It's kind of annoying actually. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: You are watching a video using *what* program? Please edit the question to show what exactly you did, what you expected to happen, what really happened. A screenshot of the video player showing the wallpaper by partial transparency would help.

Comment: I just noticed that only happens in firefox, i have a screenshot showing the problem but i don't know how to post it here sorry, I'ts my first question asked here and i don't know yet how it works

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdaspnv677zr1y5/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202018-12-23%2013-23-59.png?dl=0

Comment: Let me know if you can watch the screenshot in that link

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please try with a [video from YouTube](https://youtu.be/QWbMckU3AOQ?t=55); also, try running Firefox with an empty profile and *edit the question* to include the relevant information.

Comment: The link should work, because I tried it on my gf's phone and I can see the image. Also I tried what you suggested, open the same video in an empty profile session and the problem dissapears. That means there is something wrong with the way my profile deals with the videos? I'm actually clueless here

Comment: If the Firefox works fine with an empty profile it usually means that the undesirable behavior is caused by an extension. Try disabling the extensions one by one and see if the undesirable behavior stops.

Comment: I just did that and so far so good mate, thanks a lot. It's the gnome shell extension apparently that is causing the problem. I will keep an eye on this and see if the problem is gone for good. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianLopez, I have the same problem, Firefox shows me a background wallpaper or a window, depends on what is underneath the firefox showing a dark video. Disabling extensions didn't help. I use Manjaro+GNOME with AMD RX580 with free driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox 64.0 renders content transparent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100753/firefox-64-0-renders-content-transparent)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: [Strange "ghost images" / transparency effect in full-screen videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102427/strange-ghost-images-transparency-effect-in-full-screen-videos/1103067?noredirect=1#comment1819087_1103067)

TL;DR; -> Change `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` option to `true` in the `about:config`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that worked for me, I thought I fixed it with the solution Alex P suggested but the problem came back. Now it is definetly fixed apparently! Thanks again, It was damn annoying